# How to generate XML by reading value from collection using XDocument?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have a list of string

```
List<string> lststr = new List<string>() { "1,", "2" };
```

I need to generate the below

```
<DbRuleMappings>
  <DbRuleMapping dbDetailId="1" ruleMasterId="1" activeFlag="1" />
  <DbRuleMapping dbDetailId="1" ruleMasterId="2" activeFlag="1" />
  <DbRuleMapping dbDetailId="1" ruleMasterId="3" activeFlag="1" />
  <DbRuleMapping dbDetailId="1" ruleMasterId="4" activeFlag="1" />
  <DbRuleMapping dbDetailId = "2" ruleMasterId="1" activeFlag="1"/>
  <DbRuleMapping dbDetailId = "2" ruleMasterId="2" activeFlag="1"/>
  <DbRuleMapping dbDetailId = "2" ruleMasterId="3" activeFlag="1"/>
  <DbRuleMapping dbDetailId = "2" ruleMasterId="4" activeFlag="1"/>
 </DbRuleMappings>
```

My attempt ...not working

```
List<string> lststr = new List<string>() { "1,", "2" };            

XDocument docDBRuleMapping =
        new XDocument(
           new XElement("DbRuleMappings",
                   Enumerable.Range(1, 4).Select(x => x)
                   .Select(i => new XElement("DbRuleMapping",  
                           new XAttribute("dbDetailId", i),
                           new XAttribute("ruleMasterId", i),
                           new XAttribute("activeFlag", 1)))));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently not using `lststr` at all. You need to basically use `SelectMany` to join `lststr` with your `Enumerable.Range`. That's probably done most easily with a query expression:

```
var detailIds = new List<int> { 1, 2 };

var doc = new XDocument(new XElement("DbRuleMappings",
    from detailId in detailIds
    from ruleId in Enumerable.Range(1, 4)
    select new XElement("DbRuleMapping",  
        new XAttribute("dbDetailId", detailId),
        new XAttribute("ruleMasterId", ruleId),
        new XAttribute("activeFlag", 1))));
```

(I've changed the input to be a `List<int>` rather than a `List<string>` given the data... it would work fine with a `List<string>` if you really need that though.

If you don't like query expressions, here's the equivalent without:

```
var detailIds = new List<int> { 1, 2 };

var doc = new XDocument(new XElement("DbRuleMappings",
    detailIds.SelectMany(_ => Enumerable.Range(1, 4),
        (detailId, ruleId) => new XElement("DbRuleMapping",  
            new XAttribute("dbDetailId", detailId),
            new XAttribute("ruleMasterId", ruleId),
            new XAttribute("activeFlag", 1)))));
```

Comment: +1. Really what people should do is to post "my code not working" and telepathic powers of Jon Skeet would provide way to create nice answer :).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Well at least we knew what the OP wanted to achieve. I agree that they should have said what their current code did, but I could find that out by running it - again, better than a lot of questions :)